# Access page's html before DOM parsing is completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to have access to the html of a web page before the actual DOM parsing has completed? I would like to search through whatever amount of html has already been downloaded for certain elements and not have to wait until the entire html is downloaded. It also isn't important for scripts, css, images and other stuff to be downloaded, as I am only interested in the html content.

Comment: can you elaborate what you want to achieve?

Comment: While technically possible, it's a generally a bad idea. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: You can, just place the JS at the top of the HTML

Comment: @LucaKiebel, the dom not exists in this position ;)

Comment: I need to extract the title and description. Waiting for the entire html to be parsed just to get at this is a waste of time, as some websites have very large pages and some can take a long time to load.